# ContourPlot problem with Sinc funtion

Tags: plotting

I had a problem with ContourPlot not showing the following function for certain domain values.

The function I was looking at:
$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{x y}\right)^2$.

This function is largest at $(0,0)$ where it takes the value $0.0625$. When I enlarged the domain of the ContourPlot, *Mathematica* didn't include the center of the plot. I tried using Exclusions, RegionPlot and specifying Contours to get around this behaviour, but nothing worked. This is shown in the image below.

[image: ContourPlot problem]

Then as I was typing up this question I found the answer which I will post below.

Answer (score 3):

I realised I had used `PlotRange->All` with Plot3D and `PlotRange->Automatic` with ContourPlot. This is the source of the problem, and simply specifying the PlotRange on both plots resolves the issue, as shown in the image below.

This was one of those "you have got to be ******* kidding me moments" that are always fun to read about, but not so much fun to perform. Hopefully this post helps someone out there on the interwebs.

[image: ContourPlot problem solution]

The following code produces the above image.

```
ClearAll[r, list,range];
list = Range[-1, 1, 1/4];
size1 = 20; size2 = 24; aspect = .7; imagesize = 600; imagesize3d = 600;
f[x_, y_] := ((Sin[x/2] Sin[y/2])/(x y))^2;
max = Limit[Limit[f[x, y], x -> 0], y -> 0];

plot1[r_, range_] := 
  ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
   PlotRange -> range,
   Contours -> Range[0.01, 0.0625, 0.005], 
   ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> imagesize, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> size1], 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style[HoldForm["r"] == (r/\[Pi])*HoldForm[\[Pi]], Bold, size2], 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{#*r, # "r"} & /@ (2*list), {#*r, # "r"} & /@ (2*
        list)}];
plot3[r_, range_] := 
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r},
   PlotRange -> range,
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> size1], PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotStyle -> {Lighter[Orange]}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style[HoldForm["r"] == (r/\[Pi])*HoldForm[\[Pi]], Bold, size2], 
   AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Bold, size2], Style[y, Bold, size2], 
     Style[z, Bold, size2]}, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
   Ticks -> {{#*r, # "r"} & /@ (2*list), {#*r, # "r"} & /@ (2*list), 
     Range[0, 0.0625, 0.01]}, 
   Mesh -> {list*r, list*r}, 
   FaceGrids -> {{{0, 1, 0}, {list*r, list*max}}, {{-1, 0, 
       0}, {list*r, list*max}}}, ImageSize -> imagesize3d, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, aspect}];
image = GraphicsGrid[{{plot1[2.5 \[Pi], Automatic], 
     plot3[2.5 \[Pi], Automatic]}, {plot1[2.5 \[Pi], All], 
     plot3[2.5 \[Pi], All]}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> 1200];
imageras = Rasterize[image, ImageResolution -> 96]
```